# Probability calculation for playing a video game

Tags: probability

In this game

1. there are 10 untiered room types and 24 tiered room types. [**To be clarified**: no two rooms can ever be the same type? Each tiered room type can be tier 1-3 independently?]
2. There are three tiers.
3. The temple you visit contains 11 rooms.
4. Initially the rooms can be untiered or tier 1 of random type. [**To be clarified**: equally at random? Pick 11 out of the (10 tier 0 + 24 tier 1s) without replacement?]
5. There are 12 visits. The rooms to be visited are picked at random by the game.
6. A visit to an untiered room gives you two random tiered types you can change it at tier one. [**To be clarified**: again, equally from any of the 24 tiered room types that aren't already there?]
7. A visit to tiered room offers a choice: either upgrade the tier or change the room to another kind -- you can't choose which kind, the game picks that for you, before the choice. So whether to change or upgrade is an informed choice.
8. A tiered room changes to the same tier.
9. Upgrading a room always upgrades at least one tier with a 40% chance to upgrade two tiers. Tier three rooms are done, they won't come up in visitable rooms.
10. There are two kinds of winner rooms, if you manage to get those kinds to tier 3 rooms that counts as a win.
11. You can either do a batch of four visits or a batch of three visits and the game is structured in a way both kinds of batches take the same amount of real world time.
12. In each batch one room only can come up at once.
13. After 12 total visits, you win or lose. [**To be clarified**: is there any point to doing 3+3+4+? Do you get 2 visits in the end?]

So you can either run four batches of three rooms with more chances to change/upgrade or three batches of four rooms with less chance to change/upgrade *but* you actually run more temples overall.

I can't calculate which one yields more wins on the long run per real world time.

[Example](https://www.poewiki.net/images/1/1c/Temple_of_Atzoatl_layout.png) the Apex Of Atzoatl at the top and the Entrance are not visitable. You can see some untiered rooms: Tombs, Cloister, Cellar, Pits. Some Tier 1 rooms: Workshop, Trap Workshop, Torment Cells, Hall of Mettle, Sparring Room. And a few Tier 2 rooms: Demolition Lab, Warehouses.

Comment: Are the links between the rooms significant?

Comment: Not for this, no. That's a completely different section of the game.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach will solve the problem. With this level of complexity, I'll leave it to you to do the work.

Consider the state of the game. This can be described (using as much symmetry as possible) as a count of each type of room currently in the temple.

The relevant categories are: untiered, tier (1-3) non-winner, tier (1-2) winner, so that's a vector of 6 numbers that add up to 11 (presuming there's no point in counting winner tier 3 - you've already won). You have various constraints, such as untiered $\leq10$, total winners $\leq2$.[*]

The next thing is to calculate the following: what is the probability of winning, given this current vector of room types, with one single batch?

This will be either 3 or 4 rooms, calculated separately, for each possible vector of room types. Remember to use all the multinomial coefficients, as you're choosing 3 or 4 from this vector without replacement. For this, all you care is the probability you pick out an already-winning room, and then upgrade it to tier 3. So for starters any temple without a winning type is impossible in one batch.

Now that you have the winrate per temple status in one batch, work backwards one step. With two batches remaining, what is the success rate at each temple status? To do this, consider the probability of outright winning as you have already calculated. If however you don't win outright, you progress to a different temple state - and you have one batch remaining. That means you can use the winrate from that state and calculate your total winrate starting from two batches back.

Obviously rinse and repeat for 3 or 4 batches remaining. Since you've calculated the transition probability, just exponentiate that matrix (leave "win" as a state that always goes to itself). This is because it's a Markov chain - none of the rules change depending on which batch it is.

The last step is simply calculating what the probability of the initial state of the temple being in each status is, according to the initialization rules of the game. That weighted sum is your total winrate. In short:
$$\text{Winrate}=\vec{q}_0A^n\vec{w}$$
where $(\vec{q}_0)_i$ is the probability of starting in state $i$, $A_{ji}$ is the probability of moving from state $i$ to $j$ in one batch, $n$ is the number of batches, and $\vec{w}_i$ is whether state $i$ wins.

[*] A crude count is, according to stars and bars, split 11 rooms into (tiers 0,1,2,3), plus split the 2 winners into (nonexistent, tier 1, tier 2), so $\binom{11+3}{3}\binom{2+2}{2}=2184$. The size of this state space is well within computer capabilities, but well beyond human pen and paper.

---

**[Invalidated previous answer, since OP clarified many differences]**

You've described far too many insignificant details. Boil it down:

1. Each room has two properties, tier (untiered=0,1,2,3) and type (winner or not).
2. Rooms don't interact. When you visit a room, you only affect that room.

Now you end up with a Markov chain *per room*. Visiting a particular room gives you a roll to progress that room only.

Notice that in the end, all you care about is moving one room to the winning state. At that point, every single visit to other rooms is effectively wasted.

This means you *want* to end up with very lopsided distribution of visits to rooms, and therefore levelling out the visits is bad. The mechanics of how each room operates is irrelevant.

Simpler example:

1. You have two rooms. If you visit either room twice, you win.
2. You get to either choose to visit one random room, or both rooms.

What's the strategy to minimize total room visits?

1. Suppose both rooms have been visited once. Obviously, just visit one and win (1 more).
2. Suppose one room has been visited once. Then visiting both clearly wins (2 more). But visiting one gives you a half chance to win outright with just 1 visit, else moves you into the above state 1. (1.5 more expected).
3. Suppose neither room has been visited. Visiting both takes 3 total for sure. Visiting one takes you to the state 2., requiring 2.5 total.

---

[Edit] Actually the rooms do interact, in the form of (9): tier 3 rooms disappear from the list of visitable rooms.

However, this doesn't change the analysis, but does make the correct strategy clear. You *want* rooms to shoot up to tier 3 as quickly as possible, even non-winning ones, just to get them out of the way. In the visits analysis, again this minimizes wasted visits.

Therefore,

1. Visit 3 rooms instead of 4 per batch.
2. Always upgrade a room unless you see that it can immediately be changed to a winning type.
3. Except if you're down to 3 available rooms, throwing one away is no longer useful.

Comment: "Notice that in the end, all you care about is moving one room to the winning state. At that point, every single visit to other rooms is effectively wasted." -- you can actually have _two_ wins per temple. "levelling out the visits is bad." sorry I do not understand this one though despite it seems like the most important part of it. Processing :)

Comment: Does the simpler example capture what you want out of the problem? If there's extra details such as "having 2 wins is a better outcome", put that in the question. For the example, getting to the state "one room visited twice, one room visited once" is not better than "one room visited twice, one room not visited", hence *wasting* that visit.

Comment: Ah, hrm, yes, I get it now, if you ever get to a winning room, who cares what happened to the rest.  I will try to run the actual numbers tomorrow because it's still not clear to me whether 4x batch of 3 or 3x batch of 4 is better.

Comment: Think about it: which would make the count of visits more spread out across the rooms, and which one will do the opposite? You already noted that in the question.

Comment: Well, obviously having 4x batch of three allows more visits to a single room _but_ is that better enough to counter running less overlal?

Comment: That was the most unclear aspect of your question: what "it takes the same amount of time" means. If there's absolutely no cost to visiting a fourth room, then you just get more visits overall in the same time. Why is there even a question? Listing 4x3 and 3x4 very strongly implies those are comparable.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear: a batch, regardless whether it's 3 or 4 takes the same time.

Comment: Well: when you do a batch of 3, you can't get the same room twice. When you do a batch of 4, you get absolutely everything that the batch of 3 gives you, plus one extra room (which won't be one of the previous 3). Are room visits ever bad? Why is there even a question of whether to do 3 or 4?

Comment: Because there's only 12 visits per temple. So if you do batches of 4 then there are only three batches and you might need two (untiered -> winning type tier 1 -> tier 3) or with bad luck even three visits (untiered -> winning type tier 1 -> tier 2 -> tier 3) to create a winning room.

Comment: That completely changes the problem, and basically reverts it to the original. If you have only 12 visits total, obviously doing 4 batches of 3 is much better than 3 batches of 4. Please edit the question to ask "what gives the most wins per **real** time". At this point we need specific details on the distribution of all these draws (untiered/T1, new room types, can two rooms have the same type, etc.)

Comment: Two rooms can't have the same type, everything else is uniformly random. I am sorry for explaining this poorly.